# App crashes on Users device in UIViewController: com.apple.main-thread

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, crash, uikit, fullscreen

i use fabric.io to track the crashes on the devices of users. I get many crash reports with following stack trace:

```
0 libobjc.A.dylib 0x33e9ef46 objc_msgSend + 5
1 UIKit 0x29698225 +[UIViewController _viewControllerForFullScreenPresentationFromView:] + 196
2 UIKit 0x29697cfb -[UIWindow _scrollToTopViewsUnderScreenPointIfNecessary:resultHandler:] + 442
3 UIKit 0x29697b1f -[_UIScrollsToTopInitiatorView touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 214
4 UIKit 0x29697a41 -[UIStatusBar touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 416
5 UIKit 0x295fc245 forwardTouchMethod + 236
6 UIKit 0x294ae567 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 522
7 UIKit 0x294a7e31 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 544
8 UIKit 0x2947e759 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 196
9 UIKit 0x296f22f9 _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent + 14168
10 UIKit 0x2947d1a9 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 1352
11 CoreFoundation 0x25f27fbf __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 14
12 CoreFoundation 0x25f273cf __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 218
13 CoreFoundation 0x25f25a35 __CFRunLoopRun + 772
14 CoreFoundation 0x25e733b1 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 476
15 CoreFoundation 0x25e731c3 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
16 GraphicsServices 0x2d3d3201 GSEventRunModal + 136
17 UIKit 0x294dd43d UIApplicationMain + 1440
```

So in the whole stack trace, there is not a single line of my code. I cannot think of any reason why this happens.

Does anybody have the same problem or an idea how to approach this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have similar crash and do not see any of my code in stack trace also. Did you find the solution. If so, can you share?

Comment: well in my case, there add ui-view added and deleted several times. it appeared that the views were not properly deleted, so the os tried to call function on an object that does not exist anymore. But i could not figure out which object it was, so i replaced deletion with sliding out

Comment: Thanks for the info!! In my case, it was a double notification registration messing up whole thing..

Comment: @user2055359, I'm facing similar issues without having a clear solution, could you elaborate on what you mean by replaced deletion with sliding out? Thanks

Comment: This crash stack trace is triggered when the user taps on the status bar and it is used for the framework's "scroll to top" feature. We have experienced the same problem and it involves a view that is not in the view hierarchy anymore but is still referenced somehow. The best way to reproduce it would be to activate NSZombie debugging and tap on the status bar in various views of your application. In our case it is a private subview from UIWebviews that causes the problem when we remove the UIWebview from the view hierarchy but keep it in memory for some offscreen treatment.

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered a similar problem and the crash report I got is almost the same as yours.

You crash must be the case that app crashes when users tap on the status bar to scroll to top in a UIScrollView. This is exactly what I encountered.

The root cause is that I call [UIScrollView setContentOffset:] before viewDidAppear gets called.

Somehow if you call UIScrollView setContentOffset prior to view controller appearance, iOS system will try to retain your UIScrollView instance after it is deallocated, resulting in SIGEV or SIGBUS.

If you debug your app with Enable Zombie Objects, you will surely get something similar to

> [UIScrollView retain]: message sent to deallocated instance
>   0x1371a7600

.

If you would like to reproduce the crash, I suggest that you do the following.

1. Create two view controllers, both with UIScrollView instance added to view hierarchy.
2. Push them to navigation stack and be sure to call setContentOffset in viewDidLoad and before viewDidAppear for both of them.
3. Pop one view controller and leave the other in navigation stack
4. Tap status bar.

The solution is that you should check if view controller's view.window property is nil or not, if it is nil, do not call setContentOffset of UIScrollView instance, delay all calls to setContentOffset until view.window is non-nil.

I also write a blog post about this.Although my blog is in Chinese, I added a screenshot of the call stack at the time of a crash and you can see that the call stack is the same as the stack of this question.

https://huang.sh/2016/07/%e5%ae%9a%e4%bd%8d%e5%b4%a9%e6%ba%83uikituiviewcontroller-_viewcontrollerforfullscreenpresentationfromview/